# Memristors vs neural network nodes, what's the difference?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Knowing very little about AI, just a little puzzled by the claim that [memristors](http://www.popsci.com/technology/article/2010-12/making-machine-mind-out-memristors) may finally lead to AI that will equal, and likely pass, the power of the human brain.

So, what's the difference between memristors (hardware) vs neural network nodes (software)?

Very possible the two are complete non-related, but given that it's my understanding is neural networks are used to simulate "bio neural networks" seems to me that memristors are just the silco version of the bio version that is emulated by neural networks.

Reason I ask, is because if they're very close or the same in concept (meaning they only differ in implementation) no idea how one could make the claim that memristors will close the gap on AI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neural networks are able to form new connections. Hardware cannot do this.

Memristors are much more useful for creating fast non-volatile memory. In the future there won't be RAM and storage, but a unified memory.

Comment: @dan_waterworth: "neural networks are able to form new connections. Hardware cannot do this." Right, I agree, which makes the claim that memristors will finally enable AI a little odd to me.

Comment: @dan_waterworth: "Memristors are much more useful for creating fast non-volatile memory." Yes, that's my understanding too. "In the future there won't be RAM and storage, but a unified memory." Maybe, maybe not, there's always trade offs to be made. Most complex bio-systems have layers of memory performance and the ability for that memory to be adaptable; which would lead to to believe that there will never be a single unified layer of memory.

Comment: you could potentially create a neural network using memristors but the circuit size would be order squared the number of neurons. AI is already possible with digital computers and memristors may make this easier.

Comment: If memristors become faster than RAM and dense enough and no other technologies emerge in the intervening time I think that a unified memory is likely.

Comment: @dan_waterworth: "circuit size would be order squared the number of neurons" no idea. "AI possible with digital computers" yes, it is - but not in the sense most people think of it as being; at least as far as I know. When it's common knowledge that really AI is here, it'll likely already be beyond the understanding of any one given person, and within a short time, beyond the collective understanding of humans; if humans are in fact able to create true AI. Most AI is for very niche uses, and not allowed to grow in the wild, which is where IMHO true AI will come from.

Comment: @dan_waterworth: "If memristors become faster than RAM and dense enough and no other technologies emerge in the intervening time I think that a unified memory is likely." Maybe, but neither current history of biosystems (evolution), nor of synthetic systems leads me to believe that will be the case, if anything, synthetic systems will become increasingly diverse and layered.

Answer (score 1):

Its intended to move away from the von neumann architecture; a memory node can be a compute node. Yes, a fundamental shift. It also allows other logic operations which enables AI from a different perspective.

Comment: Thanks. In regards to, "it also allows other logic operations which enables AI from a different perspective." those would be what in plain English?

Comment: Looking into your answer it appears it's possible you misunderstood my question. The question is not if the hardware is a shift it's if the concept is a shift; it appears neural networks would be a non-von Neuman architecture; which clearly as a concept are not new. My questions is that if conceptually there's anything new about memristors, which it does not appear there is; meaning the concept of memristors has been implemented via software for years, and it would be a huge leap to say memristors would make a difference in reaching AI.

Answer (score 0):

Memristors allow in-memory computing, e.g., they can accelerate matrix-vector multiplication (MVM), bitwise operations and search operations. Also, memristor is a high-density non-volatile memory.

Since computation pattern of convolution layer is MVM and the fully-connected layer is memory-intensive, memristors can accelerate both convolution and fully-connected layers. As such, memristors can allow efficient hardware acceleration of convolution neural networks and other variants of neural networks.

However, current implementations of memristors also have several issues, such as poor reliability, hard errors. See [my survey paper](https://www.academia.edu/36504841/A_Survey_of_ReRAM-based_Architectures_for_Processing-in-memory_and_Neural_Networks) for more details on the use of memristors for accelerating neural networks and the discussion on current challenges.